# How to route lan trafic over VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, local-area-network

I have two computers connected to same VPN (hamachi) network. There are in different places.
Lets say I have this addresses:

Machine A: (rpi zero - using wifi)

```
wlan0:
    inet 192.168.2.160  netmask 255.255.255.0

ham0:
    inet 25.61.150.71  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Machine B (laptop - using wifi):

```
wlan0:
    inet 192.168.0.103  netmask 255.255.255.0

ham0:
    inet 25.72.151.72  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Each machine can ping each other. But what must I do if I want to access some other machine on Machine A network from Machine B?

For example on Machine B:

```
ping 192.168.2.123
```

192.168.2.123 is located on Machine A LAN.

I've tried this:

Machine A (as root):

```
LAN=wlan0
HAM=ham0

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $LAN -j MASQUERADE  
iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN -o $HAM -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $HAM -o $LAN -j ACCEPT
```

Machine B:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 25.61.150.71
```

But without success.

I cant ping 192.168.2.123 from machine B.

How can I do this properly?

Edit:
Commands written above seems to be correct. I've tested similar setup with freelan vpn instead of hamachi and it works.

Comment: Using addresses `25.x.x.x` like this is certainly **wrong**. Those are [allocated](https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/inetnum/25.0.0.0%20-%2025.255.255.255.json) to UK Departament of Defence. For private allocation you may only use addresses permitted by [RFC1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918). *Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices.*

Comment: Yes, but IP 25.x.x.x is offered by hamachi.

Comment: I suspected that. This means it is immediately disqualified as a professional/enterprise tool, and therefore it is offtopic here. I already opted to move this question to SuperUser, just wait somebody else confirms that and chances you'll get an answer increase. However, consider using a proper VPN which doesn't violate Internet standards even for a personal setting. Hamachi is a no-go, it is written by people who don't learn from their mistakes, as this seems to be not the first time they are stepping on this rake.

Comment: Are my commands correct? iptables stufs and ip route add *** ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually a bit more straitforward.

Ignore the `iptables` commands on `machine A` for now as that is about hiding your subnet `192.168.2.0/24` behind a NAT.

Instead focus on what is actually going on when you do a ping command.

When you send a ping to a remote ip you actually need to inform both `machine A` and `machine B` how to get the respective networks `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24`.

You got the first part right about telling `machine B` that in order to ping anything on `192.168.2.0/24` it has to go through `25.61.150.71`.

That is what you did in the command:

```
machineB> sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 25.61.150.71
```

This is possible since `machine A` and `machine B` is on the same subnet provided by Hamachi.

But any ping command also needs to send a reply back, so how does the `machine A` know where the network `192.168.0.0/24` is located?

You can tell `machine A` that the subnet `192.168.0.0/24` is located behind `25.72.151.72`.

This leads the the following command:

```
machineA> sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 25.72.151.72
```

---

However we are not quite out of the woods yet, since even though `machine A` and `machine B` knows where to send traffic to any host belonging to either net we still have the challange of how does **any other host** belonging to the `192.168.0.0/24` know how to contact `192.168.2.0/24`?

If `machine A` and `machine B` is not the default gateway for their networks, then we need to add a static route to the default gateway on either net.

For `machine A`'s default router we need to tell that `192.168.0.0/24` is reachable through `192.168.2.160`.

Similar we need to tell `machine B`'s default router that `192.168.2.0/24` is reachable through `192.168.0.103`.

After all this is done you should be able to ping from any host belonging to either net to any host belonging to the other net.